# How to change the font size of a class to make it responsive using Bootstrap4 with sass?

Tags: css, sass, responsive, twitter-bootstrap-4, typography

So, i'm working on a project using Bootstrap 4 sass and i want to make the font-size of the h3 to be responsive.

When i go to the _type.scss, the h3 property looks like this:

```
h3, .h3 { font-size: $h3-font-size; }
```

it's calling the variable $h3-font-size from _variables.scss that looks like this:
    $h3-font-size:                $font-size-base * 1.75 !default;

the $font-size-base variable looks like this:

```
$font-size-base:              1rem !default;
```

So, this far i know that the font-size of the h3 class is 1.75rem, what i want is that font-size to be 1.5rem from xs to md, and to be 1.75rem from md to lg.

i went to the Bootstrap 4 Documentation for typography and it says this:

Responsive typography refers to scaling text and components by simply adjusting the root element’s font-size within a series of media queries. Bootstrap doesn’t do this for you, but it’s fairly easy to add if you need it.

Here’s an example of it in practice. Choose whatever font-sizes and media queries you wish.

```
html {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
}
```

how do i include that in the _type.scss for the h3 to be responsive the way i want it to be? do i have to use the calc() function of css3? if i have to do that, how do i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify it different ways. You could replace the entire h3 line in your `_type.scss` with the following and modify the values to suit your needs:

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  h3, .h3 { $font-size-base * 1.25 !default; }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
  h3, .h3 { $font-size-base * 1.5 !default; }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
  h3, .h3 { $font-size-base * 1.75 !default; }
}
```

Personally I don't typically like to modify the default framework partials though, so you can easily go back to defaults.  Doing this can also create upgrade headaches later on.  So what I would do is create another partial called `_custom_type.scss`, add the above code to it, and compile it into your CSS, just make sure to add your custom overrides *after* the defaults.

Comment: When you override something just delete the !default tag so you know which you have modified. If a variable is assigned it won´t be reassigned by a !default variable.